# Stack: How to depend on a package during development?

Tags: haskell, dependency-management, cabal, haskell-stack

There is a portion of my application that would be better if published to Hackage. I still don't know exactly what it will look like, so I need to make many changes to it while working on my application.

It's very easy to just create a module in my project and iterate there, but I would like to put it in its own project so it can have its own dependencies.

How can I have my project depend on this separate package during development? It should allow for quick iteration. Here's what I tried so far:

```
# stack.yaml
packages:
- '.'
- location: ../amqp-worker

# my-application.cabal
library
  build-depends:
      base >= 4.7 && < 5
    , amqp-worker
```

But I get an error when I build:

```
$ stack build
cra-reporting-0.1.0.0: build

--  While building package cra-reporting-0.1.0.0 using:
      /Users/seanhess/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.24.0.0-ghc-8.0.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.0.0 build lib:cra-reporting exe:cra-reporting-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /Users/seanhess/projects/simple/cra-reporting/.stack-work/logs/cra-reporting-0.1.0.0.log

    Preprocessing library cra-reporting-0.1.0.0...
    [8 of 8] Compiling Simple.DataX.Worker ( src/Simple/DataX/Worker.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/Simple/DataX/Worker.o )

    /Users/seanhess/projects/simple/cra-reporting/src/Simple/DataX/Worker.hs:6:1: error:
        Failed to load interface for ‘Network.Worker’
        Perhaps you meant
          Network.Socket (needs flag -package-key network-2.6.3.1)
          Network.Wreq (from wreq-0.4.1.0)
          Network.Socks5 (needs flag -package-key socks-0.5.5)
        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

The external package seems to build fine if I run `stack build` from within its project folder.

Both projects are targeting lts-7.3

Comment: Is it possible that you didn't add the module to the exposed-modules list?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I think that's it. It is the only way I could reproduce the problem while fiddling with the default `stack new` project.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I had specified the module in the exposed-modules list. If it matters, here's what actually happened: My parent project was lts-7.2, I created the sub-project with stack new, which based it on lts-7.3. At some point I started getting errors and updated my parent project to lts-7.3. I think the error was from some kind of build artifact.

Answer (score 1):

The above example should work. I attempted this again from scratch and it works fine. The error was due to some kind of build artifact.

If it happened again I would delete .stack-work in the sub-project and rebuild.